# Concatenate json entry under the same name

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json

I'm currently trying to learn the basics of javascript and working with JSON.

I have a JSON file wherein I want to combine the imports of the same name into one entry. How would that be possible?

**Raw JSON**

```
[{
    "name": "1.date.17-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.HOUSTON", "1.person.JOHN"]
},
{
    "name": "1.date.17-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.MIAMI", "1.person.BEN", "1.person.JOHN"]
},
{
    "name": "1.date.18-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.UBER", "1.person.JOHN"]
}
]
```

**Expected output**

```
[{
    "name": "1.date.17-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.HOUSTON", "1.person.JOHN", "1.location.MIAMI", "1.person.BEN"]
},
{
    "name": "1.date.18-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.UBER", "1.person.JOHN"]
}
]
```

Any tips and suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an object to keep track of the names, we iterate through the data array using `forEach`.

Then we check if the `name` of the `item` has been passed before. If it has been passed, we merge their `imports` together. If not we add the item to the object.

To prevent duplicate `imports`, we use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which prevents duplicate elements and then we convert it back to an array using the spread `...` operator

And then we use `Object.values` to return the merged data without the `names` as keys

```js
const result = {};
const data = [{"name":"1.date.17-Nov-18","size":1000,"imports":["1.location.HOUSTON","1.person.JOHN"]},{"name":"1.date.17-Nov-18","size":1000,"imports":["1.location.MIAMI","1.person.BEN","1.person.JOHN"]},{"name":"1.date.18-Nov-18","size":1000,"imports":["1.location.UBER","1.person.JOHN"]}];

data.forEach(item => {
  if (item.name in result) result[item.name].imports = [...new Set([...item.imports, ...result[item.name].imports])];
  else result[item.name] = item;
});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: the import entry repeats if it appears both on different keys. is there a way to make it appear once only?

Comment: working as intended. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way.

```js
const data = [{"name":"1.date.17-Nov-18","size":1000,"imports":["1.location.HOUSTON","1.person.JOHN"]},{"name":"1.date.17-Nov-18","size":1000,"imports":["1.location.MIAMI","1.person.BEN","1.person.JOHN"]},{"name":"1.date.18-Nov-18","size":1000,"imports":["1.location.UBER","1.person.JOHN"]}];

const result = data.reduce((acc, {name, size, imports}) => {
  acc[name] =  acc[name] || {name: name, size: size, imports: []};
  acc[name].imports = [...new Set([...acc[name].imports, ...imports])];
  
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: The problem is `imports` need to have unique elements. See OP's expected result.

Comment: I've updated my answer by using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get the unique items. Pls, kindly take a look at it. Thanks @SomShekharMukherjee

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the array into a `Map` and then make imports unique.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: '1.date.17-Nov-18',
    size: 1000,
    imports: ['1.location.HOUSTON', '1.person.JOHN'],
  },
  {
    name: '1.date.17-Nov-18',
    size: 1000,
    imports: ['1.location.MIAMI', '1.person.BEN', '1.person.JOHN'],
  },
  {
    name: '1.date.18-Nov-18',
    size: 1000,
    imports: ['1.location.UBER', '1.person.JOHN'],
  },
];

console.log(
  Array.from(data.reduce((m, o) => (
      m.has(o.name)
        ? m.get(o.name).imports.push(...o.imports)
        : m.set(o.name, { ...o }),
      m), new Map()).values(),
    (v) => ({ ...v, imports: [...new Set(v.imports)] }))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using `Array.prototype.reduce`. As you start learning JS so I write the answer more elaborately. Try this out-

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "1.date.17-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.HOUSTON", "1.person.JOHN"]
},
{
    "name": "1.date.17-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.MIAMI", "1.person.BEN", "1.person.JOHN"]
},
{
    "name": "1.date.18-Nov-18",
    "size": 1000,
    "imports": ["1.location.UBER", "1.person.JOHN"]
}];

let res = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr.name] === undefined) {
    // If not exists then take the original current object
    acc[curr.name] = curr;
  } else {
    // If exists then push the current imports to the previous imports
    acc[curr.name].imports.push(...curr.imports);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

// Convert the object to array.
res = Object.values(res);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```